# Java Script Error while accessing the object

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have javaScript to process AWS response

```js
async function getUserOfAuthenticatedUser(event) {
    let userSub = event.requestContext.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider.split(':CognitoSignIn:')[1]
    let request = {
        UserPoolId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', // Set your cognito user pool id
        Filter: `sub = "${userSub}"`,
        Limit: 1
    }
    let users = await cognitoClient.listUsers(request).promise();
    console.log("got user:", users['Users']['Attributes']);
}
```

When I execute the code it gives me the following error

```html
UserCreateDate: 2018-09-10T22:58:01.414Z,
                                ^^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:537:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
```

If I print the user output is

```css
{ Users: 
   [ { Username: '7595c6c3-b29b-4fd5-aeb4-45c0ad2669b8',
       Attributes: [Array],
       UserCreateDate: 2018-09-10T22:58:01.414Z,
       UserLastModifiedDate: 2018-09-10T22:58:23.901Z,
       Enabled: true,
       UserStatus: 'CONFIRMED' } ] }
```

How can I access the Attributes?

Comment: What's the error you are receiving? What do you see if you just `console.log(users)` ?

Comment: Hi ioseph, I have updated the post. Thanks!

Comment: The "user output" doesn't look like the actual JSON...is that a `console.log` of the object? It's hard to tell without seeing the actual JSON text data sent by AWS what might be causing that error. Also, in your code when you do `users['Users']['Attributes']`, `Users` is an array. You would need an array index, like `users['Users'][0]['Attributes']` (or you could use the somewhat easier to type/read syntax of `users.Users[0].Attributes`)

Comment: The output I posted is the log entry for console.log("got user:", users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is an object, with an attribute `Users` which is an array of `Objects`, which each have an attribute `Attributes` which is an array.

You can see more examples in the [API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html)

To access the list of attributes of first user in the returned list:

```
console.log(users['Users'][0]['Attributes'])
```